# how to install drush on mac getting error can't connect to local mysql

Tags: 7, drush, database

I'm trying to install drush on my local macbook.
Drupal runs fine but when I try to run drush from cli:

jackBook:drupal-7 jack$ `drush status`

I'm getting the following response in the cli:

```
<h1>Additional uncaught exception thrown while handling exception.</h1>
<h2>Original</h2>
<p>PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can&amp;#039;t connect to local MySQL server through socket &amp;#039;/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock&amp;#039; (2) in drupal_is_denied() (line 1847 of /Users/jack/Sites/drupal-7/includes/bootstrap.inc).</p>
<h2>Additional</h2>
<p>PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can&amp;#039;t connect to local MySQL server through socket &amp;#039;/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock&amp;#039; (2) in system_list() (line 165 of /Users/jack/Sites/drupal-7/includes/module.inc).</p>
<hr />
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.
```

what did I do wrong?

I followed these steps: 
http://drupal.org/node/508450#comment-2352240

1. Download drush.tar.gz to your desktop (or wherever)
2. Jump across to the Terminal
   cd ~/Desktop
3. Extract it with
   tar -zxf drush.tar.gz
4. Move it to /usr/local/lib
   sudo mv drush /usr/local/lib/
5. Make it executable
   sudo chmod u+x /usr/local/lib/drush/drush
6. Then stick it in /usr/bin/ so that you can run it from anywhere
   sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/drush/drush /usr/bin/drush

And added `alias drush='/path/to/drush/drush'` to my .profile

phpinfo file:

jackBook:php jack$ `php -i`

[phpinfo](http://www.pastie.org/3119062)

as you can see pdo is enabled for mysql / mysqllite (if that is somewhat related and I'm not wrong )