# I've got `PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory` when using drush

Tags: drush

I installed Drush for the first time (so it may be a configuration error) and I'm trying to update to the latest core version of Drupal.

Drush is giving me this error - I'm on an OSX box.

```
dev5:clientnamedirectory my.name$ drush pm-update projects drupal-7.25
<h1>Additional uncaught exception thrown while handling exception.</h1>

<h2>Original</h2><p>PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory in drupal_get_installed_schema_version() (line 155 of /Users/my.name/Sites/proface/includes/install.inc).</p>

<h2>Additional</h2>

<p>PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory in system_list() (line 165 of /Users/my.name/Sites/clientnamedirectory/includes/module.inc).</p><hr />

Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.
```

Comment: Have you completed [these](http://drupal.org/node/1183204) steps?  I know it may not be exactly your issue, but it may help.

Comment: Which version of drush are you using? There is issue that seem to be identical with yours: http://drupal.org/node/832472

Comment: I'm using version drush-7.x-4.5 and drupal 7.9

Comment: added the steps that I followed to my question. Seams like similar staps you are sugessting @Chapabu

Comment: If you run `sudo drush status` do you get the same error message?

Comment: I've logged in as root `sudo su -l` and got the same error message. But It is fixed now.

Comment: You have a PHP/MySQL connection problem (not Drupal related) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412009/starting-with-zend-tutorial-zend-db-adapter-throws-exception-sqlstatehy000

Comment: I tried adding this line to my php5.3.27.ini for MAMP and it didn't work:

pdo_mysql.default_socket = /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18773/how-to-install-drush-on-mac-getting-error-cant-connect-to-local-mysql](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18773/how-to-install-drush-on-mac-getting-error-cant-connect-to-local-mysql)

Comment: @kenorb the other way around, this question is way older ;)

Comment: @FLY Should be opposite, see [Should I vote to close a duplicate question, even though it's much newer, and has more up to date answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147643/191655) This one has more views, better generic answers, and much more votes.

Comment: I see, so we should close this one, and fag a moderator to merge the questions since they are the same.

Answer (score 46):

In your database configuration in the file settings.php for the Drupal site, try changing the host to 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost.

replace the default:
'host' => 'localhost',

with:
'host' => '127.0.0.1',

I've had this error on OS X XAMPP, but the solution should apply here as well. As Clive mentioned, its a MySQL connection issue.  [This post](https://serverfault.com/questions/295285/mysql-cannot-connect-via-localhost-only-127-0-0-1) has more on the underlying issue.

Comment: Neat and simple solution. It works on a per-site basis, though, but it made the trick here.

Comment: The more popular answer does not work for me (I'm using MAMP Pro), but this one does. Thanks!

Comment: No! This might get Drush to work... but it subsequently causes Drupal to fail

Answer (score 45):

This was how I solved it on macOS:

```
sudo mkdir /var/mysql
sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock /var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Source: [Working with Drush on Mamp](https://www.drupal.org/node/1651282).

Comment: For me it was looking in "/tmp" for the mysql.sock file. So I had to create a symlink in there to my MAMP install. Just FYI for anyone that runs into that.

Answer (score 12):

#### Explanation

The [PDOException - error 2002](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-connecting.html) means that your drush can't connect to MySQL local database server through the socket file (e.g. `/tmp/mysql.sock`) as configured in your `php.ini`.

This is actually not much related to `drush` it-self, it's your PHP configuration and that error can be reproduced by:

```
php -r "new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=3306;charset=utf8;dbname=dbname', 'root', 'root');"
```

#### Fix

If your MySQL works correctly, make sure these two files:

1. `mysql_config --socket`

   or: `mysqladmin variables | grep socket`
2. `php -i | grep -w default_socket`

   or: `php -r 'phpinfo();' | grep -w default_socket`

matching and points to the same file and they both exists.

If not, check which one is correct by:

```
mysql --socket=/path/to/mysql.sock
```

then fix the problem by one of following solutions:

- make the symbolic link to point to the working `mysql.sock` unix socket (for MAMP, see [Andrew answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/99461/1908)),

  - for example, if you're using MAMP, you can make a symbolic link to the default location:

    ```
    sudo ln -vs /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql /var/mysql
    ```
- correct path of your `pdo_mysql.default_socket`, `mysql.default_socket` or `mysqli.default_socket` in your `php.ini`
- specify `unix_socket` in your `settings.php` in your `$databases` variable, e.g.

  ```
  $databases['default']['default'] = array(
    // ...
    'unix_socket' => '/var/mysql/mysql.sock',
  ```

---

#### Troubleshooting

Other edge-cases could be:

- wrong permissions (e.g. to the parent folders),
- you're out of space,
- you've multiple PHP versions, check which exactly are you using and which config are you changing,
- Debug with XDebug:

  - `echo '<?php xdebug_start_trace("/tmp/foo.log");' > init.php`
  - `drush -c init.php ev 'Database::getConnection("default", "default");'`
  - or set `xdebug.show_exception_trace=1` in your `xdebug.ini`
- Debug: on OS X with `sudo dtruss -fn mysqld`, on Linux with `strace`
- See also: [MySQL connection not working: 2002 No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1676688/55075) at SO

Answer (score 8):

I'm using MAMP Pro and had this same issue. The easiest way I could find to fix it was to add the following line to your $database array in the settings.php file.

```
'unix_socket' => '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',
```

In full it should look like this:

```
$databases = array (
    'default' =>
     array (
        'default' =>
        array (
            'database' => 'your_database_name',
            'username' => 'username',
            'password' => 'password',
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'port' => '',
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'prefix' => '',
            'unix_socket' => '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',
        ),
    ),
);
```

The exact error I was getting looked like this:

## Additional uncaught exception thrown while handling exception.

### Original

PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory in drupal_is_denied() (line 2193 of ...

### Additional

PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory in _registry_check_code() (line 3477 of ...

---

Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.

Comment: this was the quickest and easiest fix for me using MAMP

Answer (score 3):

I solved this with the following steps, similar to previous replies but not the same.

Add a symlink:

```
sudo mkdir /var/mysql
sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock /var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Find the php.ini being used:

```
php -i | grep php.ini
```

Add the following settings to php.ini:

```
pdo_mysql.default_socket= /var/mysql/mysql.sock
mysql.default_socket = /var/mysql/mysql.sock
mysqli.default_socket = /var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a configuration error in your PHP/SQL configurations. Somewhere the socket that your webserver uses and the command line uses is configured differently. I recommend checking your MySQL configuration to see what unix socket is in use, and then make sure the same value is used in all php.ini configurations and compiles.

If you can't fix the configuration the following steps should work:

1. Get the development version of Drush 5.x (http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/drush-All-versions-5.x-dev.tar.gz) and install that instead. This might cause other issues, but overall its pretty stable.
2. In your Drupal sites settings.php remove the host and port settings for the database connection and add in a 'unix_socket' => '/path/to/mysql.sock' to replace them.

If all this seems to complicated, an alternative is to change the host in setting.php from localhost to 127.0.0.1. This will make the site slower, but for a development site it may not be noticeable or important. For a production site you want to use the unix socket and should sort out the configuration.

Comment: This is really what does it. I have tested it countless times.

Answer (score 1):

Found an easier / alternative way to install drush on a Mac:

Install [homebrew](http://www.pastie.org/3119062) by pasting this in a stand alone terminal

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/gist/323731)"
```

Then add drush by running the following from the same terminal

```
brew install drush
```

Running drush status runs fine now.

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with the MySQL.com installation of MySQL, you just need to point PHP at the right location for the `.sock` file.

In your `php.ini`, add/amend these two lines:

```
mysql.default_socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
mysqli.default_socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
```

To find the location of your php.ini (it may not exist yet), use this

```
php -i | grep php.ini
```

If the `php.ini` file doesn't exist there yet, create it.

Answer (score 1):

I forgot that my local mysql runs on a unique port number so I was confused why I was getting this until I reviewed my configuration on another local site.

```
$databases['default']['default'] = array (
  'database' => 'hou',
  'username' => 'root',
  'password' => '',
  'prefix' => '',
  'host' => '127.0.0.1',
  'port' => '3306',
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'collation' => 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
);
```

Comment: I don't know why, but I changed the `'host' => 'localhost',` with `'host' => '127.0.0.1',` and it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with other answers that Drupal cannot find the mysql socket.  The other answers helped me but were incomplete for installing with the official Oracle Mysql service installed.  Namely, the default location of the mysql.sock file.  So here is a recap of my recommended answers depending on your use case:

If using mysql as included by the official MAMP package, use @Andrew Alexander's answer:

```
sudo mkdir /var/mysql
sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock /var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

For the official Oracle MYSQL:

```
sudo mkdir /var/mysql
sudo ln -s /tmp/mysql.sock /var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Answer (score 0):

For a MAMP 4 setup, the solution was checking "Make this version available on the command line."

[image: MAMP configuration]

Answer (score 0):

I got the following message in terminal:

(MAMP PRO + PHP 7)

> Blockquote
>   Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.
>   [error] PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
>   in
>   Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\PhpArrayContainer->createService()
>   Blockquote

I solved the problem with the help of these [instructions](https://www.drupal.org/node/1651282)