# How do I fix the Drush error "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory"?

Tags: drush, 9

I just updated my macos' php version using homebrew. This worked, the php version I'm currently running is 8.0.2

But doing this my Drush stopped working. When running `drush cr` I get the following error:

```
In Connection.php line 189:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

I tried several suggestions mentioned here:
[I've got `PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory` when using drush](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/99446/ive-got-pdoexception-sqlstatehy000-2002-no-such-file-or-directory-when-u)

The highest voted answer:

```
sudo mkdir /var/mysql
sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock /var/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Gives me the following feedback:

```
mkdir: /var/mysql: File exists
ln: /var/mysql/mysql.sock: File exists
```

When I then run `mysql_config --socket` I get `/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock`  as return.

I also tried changing the `.zprofile` on my computer. I added:

```
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php8.0.2/bin:$PATH
```

and

```
export DRUSH_PHP="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php8.0.2/bin/php"
```

But, as you might see, I don't really know what I'm doing and why. Can someone help me get Drush working again? I'm working on Drupal 9 websites using Drush 11 (drush -v is working).

Comment: "drush stopped working"-- what doesn't work? drush can't be found?  drush can't connect to your site?  which commands work and which don't?

Comment: Sorry, I thought I mentioned that...I updated my question

Comment: Also, if you don't understand what you're doing, you should carefully keep notes of any changes that you make to your system, because you are likely to change things that don't need to be changed, causing even more problems down the line.  If a change doesn't fix the problem, it should be undone immediately.

Comment: Are you certain MySQL is running?

Comment: Yes MYSQL is running, my sites are running smoothly.

Comment: I was on MAMP for years. Switched to DDEV. Never looked back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost` in the database connection configuration.