# Unable to connect to database when launching a new Drupal site with Lando

Tags: database, 9, installation

I tried to set up a new local drupal9 site using Lando, but it is unable to connect to the database and I am getting the following error.

```
Failed to connect to your database server. The server reports the following message: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory.
```

Checking the Lando logs shows the following.

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory in /app/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/PhpArrayContainer.php on line 79
```

I checked and it seems to be resolved by putting the location of mysql.sock file in settings.php as shown below.
[I've got `PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory` when using drush](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/99446/ive-got-pdoexception-sqlstatehy000-2002-no-such-file-or-directory-when-u)

Then I checked mysql status and found the following.

```
UNIX socket:            /opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock
```

The final result was as follows. But even if I change the host to 127.0.01, etc., the error message does not change.

```
$databases['default']['default'] = [
  'database' => 'drupal9',
  'username' => 'drupal9',
  'password' => 'drupal9',
  'host' => 'localhost',
  'port' => '3306',
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'prefix' => '',
  'unix_socket' => '/opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock',
];
```

If I've made any mistakes so far, please let me know.
Thank you.

Comment: I thought that Lando runs the database server on a different host, named "db" or similar, not "localhost".

Comment: The host is `database` unless you've specified it differently in .lando.yml. And remove the socket entry in the array, you don't need that

Comment: This wouldn't have happened with DDEV. DDEV creates the correct `settings.ddev.php` for you with all connection settings set correctly and includes it in the `setttings.php`.

Comment: Thank you. I changed it to database as commented below and it worked fine. Where can I find this hostname?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update host value in settings.php to `database`.

`localhost` is not correct for default lando configuration.

Comment: Thank you very much. I changed the host name to database and it started without problems. But how do I know that the host name is database?
lando mysql -u drupal9 -p
When I logged into mysql as above, the hostname was localhost.

Comment: @shibasaki_stack You can use the command `lando info` and you will see one of the lines will be `internal_connection: { host: 'database', port: '3306' },` under the database service.

Comment: OK, I found it. thanks.